# Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] Oracle19c

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat8, oracle19c

I am fairly new to Spring and was learning Spring with Hibernate but I'm stuck on this error. I am using Oracle 19c database and I'm using Tomcat 8.5 server.

```
    SEVERE: Context initialization failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeDao': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:702)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:716)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:591)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:170)
```

The error was too long so I have uploaded it here : https://textuploader.com/1egwb
My dispatcher-servlet.xml is

```
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.bean"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.dao"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.controller"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
    <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" id="datasource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"></property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl"></property>
        <property name="username" value="scott"></property>
        <property name="password" value="tiger"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource"></property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibenate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.example"></property>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>
    
</beans>
```

My dao file is :

```
    @Repository
    @Transactional
    public class EmployeeDao {
        @Autowired
        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
        
        public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
            return sessionFactory;
        }
    
        public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
            this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        }
    
        public EmployeeDao() {}
        
        public String registerEmployee(Employee emp) {
            try {
                Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
                session.beginTransaction();
                session.persist(emp);
                session.getTransaction().commit();
                session.close();
            }catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Failed to register "+emp.getEmpid();
            }
            return "Successfully registered "+emp.getEmpid();
        }
        
        public boolean verifyLogin(Employee emp) {
            System.out.println(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession());
            System.out.println(emp);
            return true;
        }
        
        public String loginEmployee(Employee emp) {
            try {
                Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
                CriteriaBuilder cb = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
                CriteriaQuery<Employee> cq = cb.createQuery(Employee.class);
                Root<Employee> root = cq.from(Employee.class);
                cq.select(root);
                
                Predicate predicate = cb.equal(root.get("username"), emp.getUsername());
                cq.where(predicate);
                Query<Employee> query = session.createQuery(cq);
                String actualPass = query.list().get(0).getPassword();
                if(!emp.getPassword().equals(actualPass))
                    return "Incorrect Password!";
            }catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "No Such Username Found!";
            }
            return "Welcome "+emp.getUsername();
        }
    }
```

and bean is :

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="Employee")
    public class Employee {
        @Id
        private String empid;
        
        @Column(name="username")
        private String username;
    
        @Column(name="password")
        private String password;
    
        @Column(name="email")
        private String email;
        
        public Employee() {}
    
        public String getEmpid() {
            return empid;
        }
    
        public void setEmpid(String empid) {
            this.empid = empid;
        }
    
        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }
    
        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }
    
        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }
    
        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }
    
        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }
    
        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }
    
        public Employee(String empid, String username, String password, String email) {
            this.empid = empid;
            this.username = username;
            this.password = password;
            this.email = email;
        }
        
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "EMPLOYEE("+empid+", "+username+", "+email+", "+password+")";
        }
    }
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>xxxxx</groupId>
  <artifactId>xxxxxx</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>SpringMVCHibernate Maven Webapp</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
     <groupId>jstl</groupId>
     <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
     <version>1.2</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.21.Final</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.9.RELEASE</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.9.RELEASE</version>
     </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>SpringMVCHibernate</finalName>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

I have tried to search for the internet for solutions but could not find the one which would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant part from your stack trace seems to be this one:

```
    Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
```

Can you try to set this? I think org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect is the right one. Just to check, did you add the oracle JDBC dependency?

Comment: The problem was with my odbc dependency. I was using odbc6 and when I changed to odbc10 the error was removed